# How to cite full reference name in LaTex?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am trying to cite the full reference name in LaTex for a particular reference, however, it gives the `Last Name-First Name format`, when using `\citet`.

The `BibTex` entry is:-

```
@misc{tur_working,
    author       = {US Department of Energy},
    title        = {How Do Wind Turbines Work?},
    journal      = {Department of Energy},
    year         = 2019,
    url          = {https://www.energy.gov/eere/wind/how-do-wind-turbines-work}
}
```

And when cited in text, it appears as `according to Energy(2019)`, whereas I would like it to be cited as `according to US Department of Energy (2019)`. I don't want to change the complete structure of my other references, but just for this one reference, I want the author name to be mentioned in the simple sentence style. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: By BibTeX's parsing rules, the entry's full name -- `US Department of Energy` -- has two given names (`US` and `Department`)`, a von component (`of`), and a surname component (`Energy`). By encasing the full name in  **two** pairs of curly braces, one creates the impression that the name has a single component, which must be the surname component. That way, authoryear-style citation call-outs will be to `US Department of Energy`, and the entry will be sorted under `U` rather than under `E`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination @Mico!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the way out. By using `{}` in the author field in addition to the regular brackets, the full name is displayed.

```
@misc{tur_working,

        author       = {{US Department of Energy}},
        title        = {How Do Wind Turbines Work?},
        journal      = {Department of Energy},
        year         = 2019,
        url          = {https://www.energy.gov/eere/wind/how-do-wind-turbines-work}
    }
```